# Heroku + Spring Boot: @Scheduled not running at correct times

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot

I have a Spring bean in a Boot application that looks like this:

```
@Component
public class AuthTokenCleanupJob {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AuthTokenCleanupJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthTokenRepository authTokenRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000L)
    public void cleanupTokens() {
        LOGGER.info("Deleting expired AUTH_TOKENS");
        authTokenRepository.deleteOldTokens();
        LOGGER.info("Deleted expired AUTH_TOKENS");
    }
}
```

And log messages in Heroku that look like this:

```
Jun 29 06:07:28 myapp app/web.2:  2017-06-29 13:07:28.790  INFO 4 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.myapp.jobs.AuthTokenCleanup      : Deleted expired AUTH_TOKENS 
Jun 29 14:06:04 myapp app/web.1:  2017-06-29 21:06:04.230  INFO 4 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.myapp.jobs.AuthTokenCleanup      : Deleted expired AUTH_TOKENS 
Jun 30 06:36:25 myapp app/web.2:  2017-06-30 13:36:24.882  INFO 4 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.myapp.jobs.AuthTokenCleanup      : Deleted expired AUTH_TOKENS 
Jun 30 14:31:16 myapp app/web.1:  2017-06-30 21:31:15.876  INFO 4 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.myapp.jobs.AuthTokenCleanup      : Deleted expired AUTH_TOKENS
```

Why is the job running at those times when it's supposed to be running every 5 minutes? I'm running a 1X Professional dyno for this app.

#### Update

There are only 386 rows in the PostgreSQL table being cleaned up, so I wouldn't think it's a database thing that's hanging. Also, it's a pretty bored app, so running the DBCP out of connections wouldn't make sense either I wouldn't think.

Comment: Does it run on schedule every 5 minutes locally?

Comment: Yeah it did. I split the `@Scheduled` and `@Transactional` into two beans and it seems to be working now. I guess it was a proxying issue.

Comment: Should this scheduled method only run on 1 dyno? Your log suggests it's running on web.1, web.2 - Any way to ensure the job does only run once? (to cleanup an external cache for example)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it had something to do with the way things were being proxied. I ended up splitting the `@Transactional` and `@Scheduled` out into two beans and that fixed the problem. Since I was running the local version in IntelliJ instead of running the output JAR, I'm guessing the proxies were being created differently (or in a different order, perhaps?). Either way, it works now with the following:

```
@Component
public class AuthTokenCleanupJob {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AuthTokenCleanupJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private AuthTokenCleanupService authTokenCleanupService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000L)
    public void cleanupTokens() {
        LOGGER.info("Deleting expired AUTH_TOKENS");
        authTokenCleanupService.cleanupAuthTokens();
        LOGGER.info("Deleted expired AUTH_TOKENS");
    }
}
```

-

```
@Service
@Transactional
class AuthTokenCleanupService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthTokenRepository authTokenRepository;

    def cleanupAuthTokens() {
        authTokenRepository.deleteOldTokens();
    }

}
```

*Note: AuthTokenCleanupService is Groovy code.*